# Dividir o primeiro registro de uma coluna pelo ultimo registro

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma tabela onde mostra dados informados durante o período de um mês:

```
DATA       REGISTRO
01/06/2016  
02/06/2016  
03/06/2016  
04/06/2016  
05/06/2016  50
06/06/2016  60
07/06/2016  10
08/06/2016  20
09/06/2016  50
10/06/2016  60
11/06/2016  100
12/06/2016  50
13/06/2016  10
14/06/2016  30
15/06/2016  10
16/06/2016  50
17/06/2016  10
18/06/2016  30
19/06/2016  30
20/06/2016  40
21/06/2016  50
22/06/2016  30
23/06/2016  10
24/06/2016  50
25/06/2016  10
26/06/2016  30
27/06/2016  30
28/06/2016  40
29/06/2016  50
30/06/2016  60
```

Preciso dividir o primeiro registro pelo ultimo, o problema e que o registro pode se iniciar em qualquer data,exemplos:

```
DATA       REGISTRO
01/06/2016  
02/06/2016  30
03/06/2016  20
04/06/2016  55
05/06/2016  50
06/06/2016  60
07/06/2016  10


DATA       REGISTRO
01/06/2016  
02/06/2016  
03/06/2016  20
04/06/2016  55
05/06/2016  50
06/06/2016  60
07/06/2016  10
```

Da mesma forma o ultimo. Ou seja eu precisaria conseguir identificar qual é o primeiro registro e qual é o ultimo e dividir um pelo outro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otácio, é para dividir as datas (são números internamente) ou o valor dos registros? Neste caso os valores iniciais dos registros é zero (célula em branco).

Independente do que seja, supondo que divida as datas, resolva assim considerando a célula A2 como a inicial):

```
=INDIRETO("A"&(CONT.SE(A2:A99999;">0")+1))/A2
```

O CONT.SE pega a quantidade de itens na coluna A, soma 1 para obter o número da última linha, pegando o INDIRETO da coluna A e desse número de linha, ele trará o valor da célula final e dividindo o resultado por A2 chega-se ao resultado desejado.

Veja se é isso.

Comment: Acertei a fórmula, não havia testado no momento, pois não tive tempo e agora sim, está ok!

Comment: Oi Otácio, testou a fórmula? Ficou com alguma dúvida?

Comment: Oi,agora sim,desculpa a demora no retorno. Deu sim,Obrigado.

Comment: Ok, bom trabalho, Valeu!